# flow error messages in react-native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

I was using this guide to setup vscode before starting a react native project ([tutorial link](https://hackernoon.com/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213)).
After installing **flow-bin**, reactive native library compnents are showing lots of errors. Although, the test project is running fine. 
Here is the screenshot for the same:
[image]
Can some help me for if I have missed something?
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding this in .flowconfig [options] section:
**unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters=true**
[image: screenshot]
The error asked in this question will be fixed.